# cheerio tripping up on tag with colon

Tags: node.js, xml, cheerio

using `cheerio` and trying to parse the following with `$('mods:identifier[type=DOI]').text()`

```
<mods:identifier type="DOI">https://doi.org/10.11646/zootaxa.4482.1.1</mods:identifier>
```

croaks with the error **SyntaxError: unmatched pseudo-class :identifier**

How do I get cheerio to work on tags with colons?

Answer (score 2):

I had to escape the colon with `\\`, however, the double colons were getting reduced to a single colon, so I had to escape the double colons with another set of double colons. The following worked

```
$['mods\\\\:identified[type=DOI]').text()
```

Comment: in my case I solved it with just one pair of backslashes. `$('package metadata dc\\:title')`